# 'int' object is not iterable python3?

Tags: python-3.x, object, iterable

Went through the posts about the problem, but none helped me understand the issue or resolve the problem:

```
# This is the definition of the square() function
def square(lst1):
    lst2 = []
    for num in lst1:
        lst2.append(num**2)
    return lst2

n = [4,3,2,1]

print(list(map(square, n)))
>>>
File "test.py", line 5, in square
    for num in lst1:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What is wrong with that line in the `square()` function definition, and what is the solution?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: [edit] your question, don't complete it in comments.

Comment: now `square` is too complex. `map` passes 1 integer at a time. You need `def square(n): return n*n`

Comment: You don't need `for num in lst1` in your function.  The function only receives one list element  at a time.  Just do `return lst1**2`; it's typically not useful to return one-time lists

Comment: Thanks Jean-Francois!
I copied the code from youtube, which bugged me for couple of hours. Now I understand the reason. 
However, my biggest problem with this one is: How does python distinguish the integer list and an integer if this appropriate related to my original question? Thanks again.

Comment: Woo!!! 
`Just do return lst1**2`---Never thought about this, that's amazing!

Answer (score 0):

`map` applies `square` to each item of your list.

So including a loop in `square` is redundant. `lst1` is already an integer when the function gets called.

Either do:

```
result = square(n)
```

or:

```
result = [i*i for i in n]
```

the latter is better & faster than

```
result = list(map(square,n))
```

with:

```
def square(i):
    return i*i
```

(or a `lambda`)

Comment: Thanks! 
I only focus on the use of `map()` with custom function as the first argument. I do not want to mix with more fancy stuff at this moment.